# c# locking object shared by public methods and event callback code

Tags: c#, synchronization, locking

Question regarding locking, with text referring to the sample code below...I have a class (Class1) which provides a public List property called Class1Resources.  2 methods in Class1 provide basic query capability on Class1Resources.  In addition, Class1 also subscribes to an event from a different service which provides notification that Class1 should  update this Class1Resources object.

My question is, what and where should locking be implemented such that the 2 public methods which query Class1Resources are blocked when ExternalAppCallback is executing, thereby ensuring that the query methods are always using the most current data?  Is the commented code I have in ExternalAppCallback the proper way to do this?

```
public class Class1
{
    public List<Resource> Class1Resources { get; private set; }

    public Class1()
    {
        // subscribe to external app event, with callback = ExternalAppCallback
    }

    private void ExternalAppCallback(List<Resource> updatedResourceList)
    {
        // do I put the lock here as in the code below?
        //lock(someObject)
        //{
        //    Class1Resources = new List<Resource>(updatedResourceList);
        //}

        Class1Resources = new List<Resource>(updatedResourceList);
    }

    public List<Resource> GetResourcesByCriteria1(string criteria1)
    {
        return Class1Resources.Where(r => r.Criteria1 == criteria1).ToList();
    }

    public List<Resource> GetResourcesByCriteria2(string criteria2)
    {
        return Class1Resources.Where(r => r.Criteria2 == criteria2).ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: If your code isn't re-entrant and you won't have (too many) concurrent reads then a simple lock may work pretty well. Of course from my POV the question is _where_ ExternalAppCallback is called (from code you posted I don't see any issue a simple interlocked operation can't solve but I guess when ExternalAppCalback invocation is called there is a lot of work to be done).

Comment: If I'm understanding what you're asking the simple solution is that all three of the methods shown here should share a lock when they attempt to access `Class1Resources`, which would ensure that any reads complete before the callback is executed, and vice versa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm interpreting your question as "how do I effectively make `Class1Resources` thread safe?" and so I would recommend either a classic `lock` or, if you expect writes/changes to be seldom, a `ReaderWriterLockSlim`. Here is how you'd use a `lock` in your class to ensure thread safety / consistent data:

```
public class Class1
{
    // Here's your object to lock on
    private readonly object _lockObject = new object();

    // NOTE: made this private to control how it is exposed!
    private List<Resource> Class1Resources = null;

    public Class1()
    {
        // subscribe to external app event, with callback = ExternalAppCallback
    }

    private void ExternalAppCallback(List<Resource> updatedResourceList)
    {
        // Setting a reference is always atomic, no need to lock this
        Class1Resources = new List<Resource>(updatedResourceList);
    }

    // Your new method to expose the list in a thread-safe manner
    public List<Resource> GetResources()
    {
        lock (_lockObject)
        {
            // ToList() makes a copy of the list versus maintaining the original reference
            return Class1Resources.ToList();
        }

    }

    public List<Resource> GetResourcesByCriteria1(string criteria1)
    {
        lock (_lockObject)
        {
            return Class1Resources.Where(r => r.Criteria1 == criteria1).ToList();
        }
    }

    public List<Resource> GetResourcesByCriteria2(string criteria2)
    {
        lock (_lockObject)
        {
            return Class1Resources.Where(r => r.Criteria2 == criteria2).ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

Note that in this solution, anything calling the getter of your property will not be using the lock and thus will cause thread safety issues. This is why I changed the code to make it a private member.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in choosing as the solution...was out of town with no service for several days...but it is much appreciated.